# How do I make table headers different heights from one another?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make a table with different sized headers like seen in this image:

[image]

I am able to change the widths with css, but not the height.

```
th:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:green !important;
    height:20%;
    width:5%;
    padding:5%;
}
th:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(2) {
    background-color:purple !important;
    height:50% !important;
    width:1%;
    padding:1%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pq01hc7y/2/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/pq01hc7y/4/ ? You can mess with colspan and rowspan, or create another table that lives inside of a th,

Comment: Yup.  If you just post an explanation, that looks like it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fiddle recreates the table in the document:

https://jsfiddle.net/fucrza92/

The most important part is this:

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="2">MATERIAL</th>
  <th rowspan="2">ALLOY</th>
  <th colspan="5">TUBE OD (INCH)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>0.250</th>
  <th>0.375</th>
  <th>0.500</th>
  <th>0.625</th>
  <th>0.750</th>
</tr>
```

Using `rowspan` and two header rows makes it possible for some header elements to be taller than others. The same principle is applied to columns with `colspan` for the TUBE OD element.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a minute to read through [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) - please add relevant code examples **as text** here and not as link to any other site.